# What is the closed form of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac { {{\it J}_{0}\left(n\right)} ^2}{{n}^4}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, computer-algebra-systems, bessel-functions

Using Maple I am obtaining the numerical approximation

$$0.5902373619$$

Please, let me know what is the closed form.  Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know that there is one? Most of the time, with sums such as this, there are no closed-form expressions. Do you even know  whether there's a closed-form expression for $J_0$?

Comment: I am sure that a closed form exists.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a function which has the Fourier series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_0(n)}{n^2}$ and then use [Percevals theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem). See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937152/what-is-the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-rm-j-0-left2-n) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937058/closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-fracj-02nn2/937123#937123) question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint.**

Observe that

[$$
J_0(n)=\frac 1\pi \int_0^\pi \cos (n \sin x)\:{\rm d}x \tag1
$$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9)

and that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nt}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^2 t^2}{12}+\frac{\pi t^3}{12}-\frac{t^4}{48},\quad 0\leq t\leq 2\pi. \tag2 $$
Then, due to normal convergence of the series on $[0,2\pi] $, we may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_0^2(n)}{n^4} & =\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \!\!\int_0^\pi  \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos (n \sin x)\cos (n \sin y)}{n^4}{\rm d}x\:{\rm d}y .\tag3
\end{align}
$$
We may plug 
$$
2\cos (n \sin x)\cos (n \sin y)=\cos (n(\sin x+\sin y))+\cos (n(\sin x-\sin y)) \tag4
$$
into $(3)$ and integrate as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937058/closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-fracj-02nn2/937123#937123).

Hence we obtain

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_0^2(n)}{n^4}=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-\frac{3}{64}+\frac{32}{27 \pi }. \tag5 $$

A numerical value is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_0^2(n)}{n^4} =0.5902373616900361395467798486 \ldots.
$$

---

Some details.

Identity $(2)$ may be rewritten as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nt}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^2 t^2}{12}+\frac{\pi |t|^3}{12}-\frac{t^4}{48},\quad -\pi \leq t\leq \pi. \tag6 $$

Then using $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(6)$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_0^2(n)}{n^4} =\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\pi \!\!\int_0^\pi  
\left[\left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}(\sin x+\sin y)^2+\frac{\pi }{12}(\sin x+\sin y)^3-\frac{1}{48}(\sin x+\sin y)^4\right)+\left(\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}(\sin x-\sin y)^2+\frac{\pi }{12}\left|\sin x-\sin y\right|^3-\frac{1}{48}(\sin x-\sin y)^4\right)\right]{\rm d}x\:{\rm d}y .\tag7
\end{align}
$$
We just have to be careful with the computation of the term ($|t|^3=\left({\rm Abs} (t)\right)^3$)
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\times \frac{\pi }{12}\times \int_0^\pi \!\!\int_0^\pi \left|\sin x-\sin y\right|^3 {\rm d}x\:{\rm d}y & = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\times\frac{\pi }{12} \times 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \!\!\int_0^{\pi/2} \left|\sin x-\sin y\right|^3 {\rm d}x\:{\rm d}y \\\\
&=-\frac{13}{36}+\frac{32}{27 \pi }.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @JuanOspina My method is correct, you just have to be careful with the sign of the argument $(\sin x-\sin y)$ in the series, which is not always positive, leading to consider instead $$\int_0^\pi \!\!\int_0^\pi  ({\rm Abs}(\sin x-\sin y))^3{\rm d}x\:{\rm d}y$$ probably you did not see this. Can you take it from there? Hoping to be clear. Thank you!

Comment: @JuanOspina OK, I'm going to show the computations. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Olivier, you are a STAR.  Super very nice computation, many, many thanks.

Comment: Mr. @OlivierOloa, how did you get equation 2 or 6? Could you please elaborate? To me, it looks like $\Re\,\text{Li}_4(e^{int})$. Thank you (ô‿ô)

Comment: @JuanOspina You are very welcome.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova This is a classic result [http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.8#i], it may be seen as: [The Expansion of Bernoulli Polynomials in Fourier Series.] For a proof you have [www.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/fourier.pdf] Equation (2) or (6) in the answer above is equivalent to (45) of the paper. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @OlivierOloa for the link of paper. I haven't learned Fourier Series yet. +1 for your answer

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova.  You are right it is possible to compute (6) using polylogarithm functions, specifically $Li_4$:  $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\cos \left( nt \right) }{{n}^{4}}}={\frac {1}{2}}\,{
\it polylog} \left( 4,{{\rm e}^{it}} \right) +{\frac {1}{2}}\,{\it polylog}
 \left( 4,{{\rm e}^{-it}} \right)$$

Comment: @JuanOspina In general, we can use this identity $$\text{Li}_n(e^{2\pi ix})+(-1)^n\, \text{Li}_n(e^{-2\pi ix})=-\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}B_n(x)$$
where $B_n(x)$ is the Bernoulli polynomials

Comment: Hi @Anastasiya-Romanova, you are really a Princess of Mathematics. Using your identity and the definition of the fourth Bernoulli polynomial you are able to derive the equation (2) without using Fourier series.  Congratulations.

Comment: Hello Mr. @JuanOspina, I look at your profile & you're from Medellin, Colombia. Wow! That's dangerous place in South America. I watch from CNN that drugs cartel are everywhere there, is that true?

Comment: Hi @Anastasiya-Romanova, Medellin is a beautiful place in the land. It is a city with many problems but at general the people are good and very kind. All the best, Princess of Mathematics.

Comment: Mr. @JuanOspina: Indeed, Andres Escobar is also from there. Say hi to James Rodriguez! ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Comment: Hi @Anastasiya-Romanova, you are very kind, many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using the wonderful method of Olivier implemented by Maple it is possible to prove that

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {  
{{\it J}_{0}\left(\,\alpha\,n\right)} ^{2}}{{n}^{4}}}=-{\frac {3
}{64}}\,{\alpha}^{4}+{\frac {1}{90}}\,{\pi }^{4}-{\frac {1}{12}}\,{\alpha}^{2}{
\pi }^{2}+{\frac {32}{27}}\,{\frac {{\alpha}^{3}}{\pi }}
$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {  
{{\it J}_{0}\left(\,\alpha\,n\right)}  ^{2}}{{n}^{2}}}=\frac{1}{4}\,{
\alpha}^{2}+\frac{1}{6}\,{\pi }^{2}-{\frac {4\alpha}{\pi }}
$$

For this last sum, when $\alpha =2 $ we obtain

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {  {{\it J}_{0}\left(\,2\,n\right)}
  ^{2}}{{n}^{2}}}=1+\frac{1}{6}\,{\pi }^{2}-8\,{\pi }^{-1}
$$

that is justly the result derived  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937152/what-is-the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-rm-j-0-left2-n).

Other results:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {  
{{\it J}_{0}\left(\,\alpha\,n\right)}  ^{2}}{{n}^{6}}}={\frac {1}
{945}}\,{\pi }^{6}+{\frac {1}{64}}\,{\pi }^{2}{\alpha}^{4}-{\frac {1}{
180}}\,{\pi }^{4}{\alpha}^{2}+{\frac {5}{1152}}\,{\alpha}^{6}-{\frac {
512}{3375}}\,{\frac {{\alpha}^{5}}{\pi }}
$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {  
{{\it J}_{0}\left(\,\alpha\,n\right)}  ^{2}}{{n}^{8}}}=-{\frac {{\pi }^{6}{\alpha}^{2}
}{1890}}\,+{\frac {1}{960}}\,{\pi }^{4}{\alpha}^
{4}-{\frac {35}{147456}}\,{\alpha}^{8}-{\frac {5}{3456}}\,{\pi }^{2}{
\alpha}^{6}+{\frac {1}{9450}}\,{\pi }^{8}+{\frac {4096}{385875}}\,{
\frac {{\alpha}^{7}}{\pi }}
$$

Comment: Nice results! Thank you. +1

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks.   These results were obtained using Maple with your equations (1), (3) and (7).  Your equation (4) was not used. I am using the evaluation of (3) in terms of the polylogaritm function given by Maple. Anastasiya-Romanova is noting that point.  Again, many thanks.  All the best.